# How to extend a basis to a Hamel basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I always read "take an orthonormal basis of say $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, then extend it to a Hamel basis". Can you please explain how this "extension is possible"?

Thanks.

Math

Comment: It requires a choice-like principle, so it won't be constructive...

Comment: Why don't we content ourselves with just that orthonormal basis? Why do we pass to a Hamel basis? For instance, like in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178787/invertible-unbounded-linear-maps-defined-on-a-hilbert-space

Comment: My question is if we already know an orthonormal basis, whe do we care about a Hamel basis?

Comment: That was not your original question. The motivation to do it should become clear from the rest of the proof.

Comment: A. Pongrácz, I still don't see why. Sorry if this is silly!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing a Hamel Basis with a Schauder basis. For example in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$
you can find a Schauder basis by taking the set of vectors $e_i(j)= \delta_{ij}, i\in \mathbb{N}$

To see that this forms a Schauder basis, clearly you will be able to write any (countable, infinitely large) vector, as an infinite sum of these unit vectors. Furthermore, these even form an orthonormal Schauder basis with respect to the scalar product in $\ell ^2$.

However, sometimes you need the existence of a Hamel Basis, which has the property, that every element from your space can be written as a *finite* sum of vectors from the Hamel Basis. The existence of such a Hamel Basis typically requires the Axiom of Choice and therefore you will not be able to constructively write down a Hamel Basis of $\ell ^2$ for example.

Comment: Thanks GreenLogic.

Answer (score 1):

Note that orthonormal base is different from Hamel base because the later one is a pure algebraic concept. Note that an orthonormal base is always independent. However, the linear span of an orthonormal base may be strictly smaller than the Hilbert space.

Def: We say that a collection of vectors $C$ is independent if for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in C$, scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i =0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1=\alpha_2=\ldots=\alpha_n=0$.

The idea is to apply Zorn's lemma:
Let $C_0$ be a collection of vectors and suppose that $C_0$ is independent. Define $\mathcal{F} =\{C\mid C_0\subseteq C\mbox{ and } C \mbox{ is independent.}\}$. Then $(\mathcal{F},\subseteq)$ is a partially ordered system. Let $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a chain (i.e, $(\mathcal{S},\subseteq)$ is linearly ordered). Define $C=\cup \mathcal{S}$. It can be proved that $C\in\mathcal{F}$ and $C$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal{S}$ in the sense that: $S\subseteq C$ for any $S\in\mathcal{S}$.
By Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal{F}$ contains a maximal element (which is not unique in general). Let $M\in\mathcal{F}$ be a maximal element. It is routine to show that $M$ is a Hamel base that contains $C$.

Comment: Great Danny! You've made things much clearer.